# Derivative of a complex integral function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $z_0 \in \Omega$, $\rho\geq 0$ such that
$$ U = \{ z_0 + x + iy \mid |x|\leq \rho, |y|\leq \rho \} \subset \Omega. $$
Suppose $f$ is an holomorphic function on $\Omega$.
For $w = z_0 + x +iy \in U$ we define
$$ F(w) = \int_0^x f(z_0+t)\, dt + i\int_0^y f(z_0 + x + it)\, dt.$$
I want to show that $\partial_xF(w) = f(w)$ and $\partial_yF(w)=if(w)$.
I tried to rewrite both integrals in $F$ as integrals with parameters but I doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Presumably the $z$ in your integrals should be $z_0$?

Comment: @JosephHarrison Yes, it's fixed !

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry I forgot it. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is holomorphic on $U,$
$$F(w)=\int_{z_0}^wf(z)dz$$ (along any path in $U$)
hence
$$F'=f.$$
On the other hand, by the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations),
$$F'=\partial_xF=-i\partial_yF,$$
whence your two equalities.